# Nullpointer when trying to update listview

Tags: android, methods, nullpointerexception, call

In my MainActivity class, I have a method `listview_fuellen` that fills my listview.

```
public void listview_fuellen(){
        DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvKinder);
    Cursor c = db.select();
    int count = c.getCount();
    String values[] = new String[count+1];

    List<String> auswahl = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$1" + c.getCount());
    while(c.moveToNext())
    { 
        values[i]= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
        auswahl.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS" + auswahl.get(i).toString());
        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.list_content, auswahl);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Now, in a different class where I add data to the database that the listview shows, I tried to call this method.

```
db.insert(name, zeit, geschlecht);                  
MainActivity ma = new MainActivity();
ma.listview_fuellen();
```

The constructor of MainActivity is a default constructor:

```
public void MainActivity(){

}
```

Now, when I execute my app, I get a NullpointerException for my method `listview_fuellen()`:

```
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at com.example.unserekinder.MainActivity.listview_fuellen(MainActivity.java:129)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at com.example.unserekinder.NeuesKind$1.onClick(NeuesKind.java:57)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-07 14:08:17.609: E/AndroidRuntime(25654):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Do MainActivity implement ListActivity? If so, should you not use Intent to create a instance of it instead of new?

Comment: so, you are creating new instance of the your MainActivity class and you expect to update another instance that is already running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try read about Activity life cycle

Activity Instantiation and method calling everything will be handle by Android through life cycle methods.

Place your code in `onCreate(Bundle savedinstancestate)` overriden method of your `Activity`.

And when you want navigate to the second Activity use `intent` to do that

```
Intent i=new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: But this would mean that I come to my MainActivity view, doesn´t it? Isn´t it possible to stay at my second view but updating the listview in the first view?

Comment: @user896692 Just answer my question, How do you able to see listview in FirstActivity, when you are in SecondActivity? this will answer your question.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible that if the user presses the return button on the mobile phone that the first view refreshes? The listview_fuellen() method call is in the onCreate() but there is no refresh.

Comment: @user896692 yes this is good question, yes it is possible...override onBackPressed method in your secondActivity and startActivity first Activity in that

Answer (score 1):

You don't open new Activities using `new Activity()`, but with `startActivity(new Intent(...))` instead. More information here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html